# Converting an existing Excel file encoding to UTF8

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an existing excel file that when I try to import using Import-Excel command has an error of "'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 2790: ordinal not in range(128)". In order to solve that, I opted to convert that file  into UTF8 encoding first before importing, but there is another error when importing.

Here's what I have:

```
Get-Content -Path $ExcelFile | Set-Content -Path $UTF8File -Encoding UTF8 -Force
$data = Import-Excel -Path $UTF8File -WorkSheetname $Sheet
```

this is the error upon importing:

`Stream length must be non-negative and less than 2^31`

I also try to encode using this:

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8    
$encDownloadFile =$enc.GetBytes($DownloadFile)
```

But I also have an error in importing the excel file.

Comment: `'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position ...` looks like a _python_ string error. What exact command did you run to get that error?

Comment: An excel file is binary and you can't use any type encoding on binary data.

Comment: Is this issue related to Rundeck?